# Ways to minimize lag in Sumerien IDE Update time

Tags: amazon-sumerian

It honestly feels like I'm using a Windows 2K machine that is 20 years old...

It seems: Every single thing is laggy in Sumerian. Adding a component or even changing a component property, or even selecting an entity.

Is there a way to minimize the lag? To be able to select an entity and modify a component in that entity without waiting 20 seconds for the lag spinner?

Comment: I don't experience the lag you're describing. I also don't see such a lag when I watch Amazon's live tutorials on their "Amazon Sumerian" YouTube channel. Could you post a video demonstrating the issue you're seeing?

Comment: I think this is dependent on internet connectivity settings. I notice this when my connection speed drops below 1Mbps - rather inconvenient when editing on the go using phone hotspots etc